# MySQL Summation of Group inside larger Recordset

Tags: mysql

I have an interesting situation.  I will post the SQL then explain.

```
SELECT 
    `c`.`clusterName` AS `clusterName`,
    DATE_FORMAT(`p`.`insertedTS`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `insertedDate`,
    MAX(`p`.`maxMemory`) AS `peakMaxMemory`,
    MIN(`p`.`maxMemory`) AS `minMaxMemory`,
    MAX(`p`.`usedMem`) AS `peakUsedMem`,
    MIN(`p`.`usedMem`) AS `minUsedMem`,
    MAX(`p`.`availMem`) AS `peakAvailMem`,
    MIN(`p`.`availMem`) AS `minAvailMem`,
    MAX(`p`.`numPoweredOnVms`) AS `peakPoweredOnVms`,
    MIN(`p`.`numPoweredOnVms`) AS `minPoweredOnVms`,
    (MAX(`p`.`maxMemory`) - MIN(`p`.`maxMemory`)) AS `deltaMaxMemory`,
    (MAX(`p`.`usedMem`) - MIN(`p`.`usedMem`)) AS `deltaUsedMem`,
    (MAX(`p`.`availMem`) - MIN(`p`.`availMem`)) AS `deltaAvailMem`,
    (MAX(`p`.`numPoweredOnVms`) - MIN(`p`.`numPoweredOnVms`)) AS `deltaPoweredOnVms`
FROM
    (`vtrend`.`clusters` `c`
    JOIN `vtrend`.`capacityDataRawPOSH` `p` ON ((`c`.`clusterID` = `p`.`clusterID`)))
GROUP BY `c`.`clusterName` , DATE_FORMAT(`p`.`insertedTS`, '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY `c`.`clusterName`
```

The results look like this:

```
clusterName,insertedDate,peakMaxMemory,minMaxMemory,peakUsedMem,minUsedMem,peakAvailMem,minAvailMem,peakPoweredOnVms,minPoweredOnVms,deltaMaxMemory,deltaUsedMem,deltaAvailMem,deltaPoweredOnVms
Some-Cluster,2016-09-20,221,221,111,111,111,111,17,17,0,0,0,0
Some-Cluster,2016-09-21,221,221,111,111,111,111,17,17,0,0,0,0
Some-Cluster,2016-09-22,221,221,111,111,111,111,17,17,0,0,0,0
Some-Cluster,2016-09-23,221,221,111,111,111,111,17,17,0,0,0,0
Some-Cluster,2016-09-24,221,221,111,111,111,111,17,16,0,0,0,1
Some-Cluster,2016-09-25,221,221,111,111,111,111,17,17,0,0,0,0
Some-Cluster,2016-09-26,221,221,111,111,111,111,17,17,0,0,0,0
Some-Cluster,2016-09-27,221,221,111,111,111,111,17,17,0,0,0,0
Some-Cluster,2016-09-28,221,221,111,111,111,111,17,15,0,0,0,2
Some-Cluster,2016-09-29,221,221,111,111,111,111,17,17,0,0,0,0
```

So what I am trying to accomplish (and failing) is to add a column at the end that will show wither the numPoweredOnVms count has increased or decreased over the day.  Since each of the records above represents the grouping of an entire day, which the data is entered every 15 minutes, I'm hoping to be able to look at numPoweredOnVms for the first record and the day and subtract the last record of the day from that and either get a positive (increase) or negative (decrease) count that I can use an IF statement on to present the "increase" or "decrease" text with.

Here's a sample of the raw data:

```
idcapacityDataRaw,insertedTS,clusterID,totalRamGb,maxMemory,availMem,usedMem,actualUsageRamGb,totalCpuMhz,maxMhz,usedMhz,numPoweredOnVms
739,"2016-09-20 16:50:12",29,384,221,111,111,111,268032,178688,3394,17
976,"2016-09-20 21:50:42",29,384,221,111,111,111,268032,178688,4072,17
1074,"2016-09-20 22:13:07",29,384,221,111,111,111,268032,178688,4683,17
1172,"2016-09-20 22:35:36",29,384,221,111,111,111,268032,178688,3916,17
1270,"2016-09-20 22:58:01",29,384,221,111,111,111,268032,178688,3857,17
1365,"2016-09-20 23:21:06",29,384,221,111,111,111,268032,178688,7867,17
1463,"2016-09-20 23:43:37",29,384,221,111,111,111,268032,178688,3971,17
1575,"2016-09-21 00:11:05",29,384,221,111,111,111,268032,178688,8196,17
2149,"2016-09-21 19:13:33",29,384,221,111,111,111,268032,178688,3758,17
2495,"2016-09-21 21:01:48",29,384,221,111,111,111,268032,178688,3927,16
```

So basically I would want to be able to pull the numPoweredOnVms from the first record and the last record of the day and subtract them.  Now the fun part is how to do this for multiple clusters over multiple days?  I'm thinking that I would maybe need to do a separate view of the raw data and calculate that record by record then use that view as the backing for this query, just not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your original query as a subquery, and have it return the first and last timestamps from each day. Then join back with the table to get the value of that column at each of these times.

```
SELECT c.clusterName, p.*,
       CASE SIGN(plast.numPoweredOnVms  > pfirst.numPoweredOnVms)
            WHEN -1 THEN 'Decrease'
            WHEN 0 THEN 'No change'
            ELSE 'Increase'
       END AS changePoweredOnVms
FROM vtrend.clusters AS c
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        clusterID,
        DATE(`insertedTS`) AS `insertedDate`,
        MAX(`maxMemory`) AS `peakMaxMemory`,
        MIN(`maxMemory`) AS `minMaxMemory`,
        MAX(`usedMem`) AS `peakUsedMem`,
        MIN(`usedMem`) AS `minUsedMem`,
        MAX(`availMem`) AS `peakAvailMem`,
        MIN(`availMem`) AS `minAvailMem`,
        MAX(`numPoweredOnVms`) AS `peakPoweredOnVms`,
        MIN(`numPoweredOnVms`) AS `minPoweredOnVms`,
        (MAX(`maxMemory`) - MIN(`maxMemory`)) AS `deltaMaxMemory`,
        (MAX(`usedMem`) - MIN(`usedMem`)) AS `deltaUsedMem`,
        (MAX(`availMem`) - MIN(`availMem`)) AS `deltaAvailMem`,
        (MAX(`numPoweredOnVms`) - MIN(`numPoweredOnVms`)) AS `deltaPoweredOnVms`
        MIN(insertedTS) AS firstTS,
        MAX(insertedTS) AS lastTS
    FROM `vtrend`.`capacityDataRawPOSH`
    GROUP BY clusterID, insertedDate) AS p ON p.clusterID = c.clusterID
JOIN vtrend.capacityDataRawPOSH AS pfirst ON pfirst.clusterID = p.clusterID AND pfirst.insertedTS = p.firstTS
JOIN vtrend.capacityDataRawPOSH AS plast ON plast.clusterID = p.clusterID AND plast.insertedTS = p.lastTS
```

Also, use `DATE(insertedTS)` rather than `DATE_FORMAT(insertedTS, '%Y-%m-%d')` to convert a timestamp to a date. `%Y-%m-%d` is the default format used when displaying dates.

Comment: Holy cow, not sure from what deep crevice that code came from but it did the trick with one slight modification; the subquery for the join needed to have the clusterID column included, otherwise flawless and fast!  I did modify the initial `p`.* selection stance to include only the `p` rows I wanted since the need for adding the clusterID column.

Alright, now that that is done, time to figure out how to make a view from this, should be a hoot!

Comment: I ended up putting the subquery into its own view then referencing the view as 'p' and that works like a charm. After really looking at this I can now see how it works and damn if it's still not quick as all get out.